# Oracle derby current_date issue

Tags: oracle, date, derby, date-arithmetic

I have a query that is supposed to be running on oracle ,
Here is the snippet

```
select
        username,
        CASE WHEN eff_dt <= CURRENT_DATE and ((trmn_dt is null) or (trmn_dt > CURRENT_DATE)) THEN 'Y'
            ELSE 'N'
```

but we also have couple of derby based unit tests that run same query.

Now the thing is I want to change it to either use `SYSDATE` or use `CURRENT_DATE+1/24`.
(to fix central and east coast client-server time zone diff issue)

But `SYSDATE`is not supported by derby and arithmetic syntax of derby is different from oracle .

How do I fix this road block?

Comment: Any reason not to run Oracle Express to be able to test on as similar a DBMS as possible? http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/products/express-edition/overview/index.html?origref=http://www.google.se/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CC8QFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.oracle.com%2Ftechnetwork%2Fdatabase%2Fexpress-edition%2Foverview%2Findex.html&ei=Z4JhT82uOuj_4QS29pn-Bw&usg=AFQjCNFOJiAhUUQvPBsNyORhipe7zzPZpA&sig2=YSfSfTVuVnImCqz6TXHSYg

Answer (score 0):

I'm not to familiar with derby, but you can probably create a function that can return the right date. Then create a similar function in oracle with the same name.
Your query will look then (both in oracle and derby) like this:

```
select username,
       CASE WHEN eff_dt <= YOUR_FUNCTION_NAME and ((trmn_dt is null) 
              or (trmn_dt > YOUR_FUNCTION_NAME)) THEN 'Y'
            ELSE 'N'
```